# Postgresql Distinct Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

How can i get the minutes distinct value with timestamp ...
Like , if table contains 1 minute 100 records are there...so i want count of records present or not per minute ...
For example,

`SELECT DISTINCT(timestamp) FROM customers WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE`

**Result** should be ..like

```
timestamp         record
30-12-2019 11:30  5
30-12-2019 11:31  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute', timestamp) as timestamp, COUNT(*) as record
FROM customers
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', timestamp)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', timestamp)
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be `::date` conversion for `timestamp` column including `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT timestamp, count(*)
  FROM tab
 WHERE timestamp::date = current_date
GROUP BY timestamp
```

<kbd>[Demo for current day](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bf57f59a76e5aa1eeac26d07dcbb79a9)</kbd>

`timestamp::date` might be replaced with `date(timestamp)` like in your case.

**Update :** If the table contains data with precision upto microseconds, then

```
SELECT to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), count(*)
  FROM tab
 WHERE date(timestamp) = current_date
 GROUP BY to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

might be considered.

Comment: Using `GROUP BY timestamp` might not be what's wanted as timestamp has high resolution (e.g. microseconds).

Comment: yes, you're right for the option including microseconds precision @karmakaze , but no problem exists for the data in OP's case.